# how to write a message in Search Script

Tags: php

i'd like to know how i could write a message in my search script when the name i look for doesn't exist.
my script show me this "0 results for 'name'" i want to write my own message,
and this is my php code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
$search_output = "";

if (isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] !="" ){
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
if($_POST['filter1'] == "Nom de medicament"){
    $sqlCommand = "(SELECT COL_8, COL_17 AS medicament, COL_32 FROM tbl_name WHERE COL_17 LIKE '%$searchquery%' ) ";
    }
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('signup');       
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

        $search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr/>$sqlCommand<hr />";
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $COL_8 = $row["COL_8"];
            $medicament = $row["medicament"];
                $COL_32 = $row["COL_32"];
            $search_output = "Prix: $COL_8 - $medicament - Quantit&eacute;: $COL_32 <br/>";
                } // close while
}
?>
```

can someone help me we that please.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change this line

```
$search_output .= "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr/>$sqlCommand<hr />";
```

to

```
$search_output .= "<hr />Your own message<hr/>$sqlCommand<hr />";
```

Feel free to use `$count` and `$searchquery` which are variables containing the number of results (none) and the name that was searched.